# trouble importing classes and constants in java

Tags: java

I have a class that looks like this:

```
package module_4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class monthPrinter {
    // just does not need to be public
    private static final String[] DAYS = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};

    // will be used by the other program that loops through all the months of a year so needs to be public
    public static final String[] MONTH_ARRAY = new String[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
}
```

I have another class that is trying to use this class that looks like this:

```
package module_4;

public class monthPrinterInYear {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (String month : monthPrinter.MONTH_ARRAY) {
            System.out.println(month);
        }
    }
}
```

My compiler error looks like this:

```
javac monthPrinterInYear.java
monthPrinterInYear.java:5: error: cannot find symbol for (String month : monthPrinter.MONTH_ARRAY) {
                                                                         ^
symbol:   variable monthPrinter
location: class monthPrinterInYear
1 error
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd like access to that `MONTH_ARRAY` constant but I can't seem to get at it.

Comment: Please follow standard naming conventions.  Class names should begin with an uppercase letter.  Are you following the standard layout for source code?

Comment: where is your compile error?

Comment: You don't need to import classes from the same package.

Comment: Please correct your question to provide the compiler error statements

Comment: static import is only for fields on classes and interfaces. Which is almost verbatim what the error message is telling you. You want a non-static import.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your naming convention to follow the standard.  Make sure your source code is in the appropriate relative locations as expected by the compiler.  Are you properly naming the subfolders by the package names?

Comment: Where is the monthPrinter.java file?

Comment: same package as monthPrinter

Comment: What is the current directory when you run javac?

Comment: You need to be one level above so the package folder can be found.  Or use javac -sourcepath ..

Answer (score 0):

You are not compiling `monthPrinter` but only trying to compile `monthPrinterInYear` which is making the trouble. Just keep the both `monthPrinter.java` and  `monthPrinterInYear.java` in the same directory named `module_4` and navigate to that directory and run the command:

```
javac *.java
```

This will try to compile all the java files within that directory. And it is important - to run the compiled file, navigate one folder backward i.e. navigate to the parent directory where `module_4` is remaining and issue the command:

```
java module_4.monthPrinterInYear
```